# Geolocation stop working after turning off/on Location service, Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, geolocation

I have a big problem and I just cant solve it. I have an app, written in Flash Develop, for clocking in and out Employees and tracking their location during the work, and track their location when they clock in/out. Everything is working just fine when location service is on all the time. But if employee want to turn off location service (to hide his position, for example) and when turn it on back, application just won't work properly - it is always telling that Location us muted (turned off). After quitting application and starting again, it resumes fine.

Any suggestions?

Code I'm using:

I needed custom event for firing location events...

```
package MyEvents {
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class GeoLocUpdateEvent extends Event {
        public static const GEOLOC_UPDATED:String = "GEOLOC_UPDATED";
        public static const GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED:String = "GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED";
        public static const GEOLOC_MUTED:String = "GEOLOC_MUTED";
        public var latitude:Number;
        public var longitude:Number;
        public var precision:Number;
        public function GeoLocUpdateEvent(type:String) { super(type); }
    }
}
```

Class which is actually capturing geolocation when asked:

```
package Utils.Geoloc {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.GeolocationEvent;
    import flash.sensors.Geolocation;
    import MyEvents.GeoLocUpdateEvent;

    public class getGeoloc extends Sprite {
        private var counter:int;
        private var _geo:Geolocation;
        public function getGeoloc() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, deleteListeners);
        }
        public function getloc():void {
            counter=1;
            _geo = new Geolocation();
            if (Geolocation.isSupported) {
                if (!_geo.muted) {
                    _geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, geolocationUpdateHandler);
                    _geo.setRequestedUpdateInterval(1500);
                } else {
                    var custEvent:GeoLocUpdateEvent = new GeoLocUpdateEvent(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED);
                    this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);
                    _geo = null;
                }
            } else {
                custEvent = new GeoLocUpdateEvent(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED);
                this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);
                _geo = null;
            }
        }
        private function geolocationUpdateHandler(ev:GeolocationEvent):void {
            counter--;
            if (counter<0) {
                if (ev.horizontalAccuracy < 40) {
                    var custEvent:GeoLocUpdateEvent = new GeoLocUpdateEvent(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED);
                    custEvent.latitude = ev.latitude;
                    custEvent.longitude = ev.longitude;
                    custEvent.precision = ev.horizontalAccuracy;
                    this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);
                    _geo.removeEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, geolocationUpdateHandler);
                    _geo = null;
                }
            }
        }
        private function deleteListeners(ev:Event):void {
            _geo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And class which is running all the time (when employee is working, with clock-in / clock-out functions. It is checking every 5 minutes location and storing it to database.

```
package Utils.Geoloc {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import MyEvents.GeoLocUpdateEvent;

    public class GeoLocWhileWorking extends Sprite {
        private var _geo:getGeoloc;
        private var Tim:Timer;
        private var intervalToRun:Number = 300000;

        public function GeoLocWhileWorking() {

        }

        /********** while working **********/
        private function check(e:TimerEvent):void {
            if (Globals.atWork) {   //global indicates employee has clocked-in
                _geo = new getGeoloc();
                _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED, geolocationUpdateHandler);
                _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED, geolocationUpdateHandlerMuted);
                _geo.getloc();
                Tim.stop();
                Tim.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, check);
                Tim = null;
            }
        }
        private function geolocationUpdateHandler(ev:GeoLocUpdateEvent):void {
            Globals.mainStage.SQL.locationrecord(0, 0, ev.latitude, ev.longitude, ev.precision);
            continueTimer();
        }
        private function geolocationUpdateHandlerMuted(ev:GeoLocUpdateEvent):void {
            Globals.mainStage.SQL.locationrecord(0,0,0,0,0);  //stores zero values if location is turned off while working
            continueTimer();
        }
        private function continueTimer():void {
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED, geolocationUpdateHandler);
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED, geolocationUpdateHandlerMuted);
            _geo = null;
            Tim = new Timer(intervalToRun);
            Tim.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, check);
            Tim.start();
        }

        /********** start/stop working **********/
        public function startworking():void {
            Globals.isEmployeeStarting = 1;
            Globals.isEmployeeEnding = 0;
            _geo = new getGeoloc();
            _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED, h1Updated);
            _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED, hMuted);
            _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED, hNotSupported);
            _geo.getloc();
        }
        public function stopworking():void {
            Globals.isEmployeeStarting = 0;
            Globals.isEmployeeEnding = 1;
            if (Tim) {
                if (Tim.running) {
                    Tim.stop();
                    Tim.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, check);
                    Tim = null;
                }
            }
            _geo = new getGeoloc();
            _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED, h1Updated);
            _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED, hMuted);
            _geo.addEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED, hNotSupported);
            _geo.getloc();
        }
        private function h1Updated(ev:GeoLocUpdateEvent):void {
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED, h1Updated);
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED, hMuted);
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED, hNotSupported);
            _geo = null;
            if (Globals.isEmployeeStarting == 1) {
                Tim = new Timer(intervalToRun);
                Tim.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, check);
                Tim.start();

                Globals.mainStage.SQL.locationrecord(1, 0, ev.latitude, ev.longitude, ev.precision);
                Globals.isEmployeeStarting = 0;
                Globals.isEmployeeEnding = 0;
                Globals.atWork = true;
                //... other stuff related to start working
            } else if (Globals.isEmployeeEnding == 1) {
                Globals.mainStage.SQL.locationrecord(0, 1, ev.latitude, ev.longitude, ev.precision);
                Globals.isEmployeeStarting = 0;
                Globals.isEmployeeEnding = 0;
                Globals.atWork = false;
                //... other stuff related to start working
            }
        }
        private function hNotSupported(ev:GeoLocUpdateEvent):void {
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED, h1Updated);
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED, hMuted);
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED, hNotSupported);
            _geo = null;
            var custEvent:GeoLocUpdateEvent = new GeoLocUpdateEvent(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED);
            this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);
        }
        private function hMuted(ev:GeoLocUpdateEvent):void {
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_UPDATED, h1Updated);
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED, hMuted);
            _geo.removeEventListener(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_NOTSUPPORTED, hNotSupported);
            _geo = null;
            var custEvent:GeoLocUpdateEvent = new GeoLocUpdateEvent(GeoLocUpdateEvent.GEOLOC_MUTED);
            this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

After location service is turned off, geolocation object is muted forever, even after locatgion service is turned on. I always receive zeros as an answer, even they cannot check-out because "location service is turned off"...

Comment: You can use the `StatusEvent.STATUS` event to detect if your `Geolocation` object is not muted to start listening to the `GeolocationEvent.UPDATE` event ...

Comment: I think I didn't explain well. When App is started and Location service is on, everything works like a charm. While app is running, if employee turns of Location service, application is working as expected, it is firing event that location has been muted. But, after employee turn back on Location service, it is still firing muted event, no way to force it to fire regular UPDATED event.

Comment: But I don't see in your code how do you do to detect that the Geolocation is turned on ( after it's turned off by the user ) ?!

Comment: Because it is always firing MUTED event... not UPDATE... mean `_geo.muted` is always true after turning back...

Comment: I think that you haven't understood what I meant. How do you want to know if the Geolocation is active (turned on by the user) again if you delete the Geolocation object and all its events listener ? Sure after that you will never get `_geo.muted` false because you can not know anything about it ! That's why you should use the `StatusEvent.STATUS` event (you can remove the other event listeners if you want) on your Geolocation object to detect if the service is turned on again. Take a look on [this example](http://goo.gl/OFv8F2) from Adobe and you will see what I mean.

Comment: If you look briefly in my code, you will see that I'm closing geolocation object when I got a result from it, to save the battery life. So, every single time geolocation object have been initiaded, and always (after turning location service back on) giving `_geo.muted` to true. Frankly, I didn't tried code like in Adobe example, but if you see it is again checking it's `muted` property which is always `true` after switching location service off/on. I think that should be bug in Adobe Air.

Comment: I don't understand where is the bug in Adobe AIR that you are talking about ?! The `status` event is fired everytime when the user switch on ( muted == false ) or off ( muted == true ) the Geolocation service of his device !

Comment: We do not understand each other. I agree that Geolocation object can have that `StatusEvent.STATUS` event when it is open (active). I told you, every 5 minutes I initialize new Geolocation object, and when I receive coordinates, I shut it down. Problem occurs AFTER turning on location, because newly created Geolocation object have property `muted` set to true...

Comment: OK, no problem. I see what you mean. I tested it and I got the same behavior when using `geo = null` after an update event otherwise it's working fine. Try it and tell me.